# What is an active session in a Java web application?

Tags: java, session, tomcat

What are "active sessions" in tomcat? I am trying to monitor active sessions for a Java web application. But the values I am getting are not matching with number of people using web application. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the number of active sessions is the number of existing or previous browser or other connections with an unique jSESSIONID cookie value. As soon as someone hits your webpage with a browser a new session is initiated and an unique JSESSIONID is assigned to this session. If next hit is performed with the same JSESSIONID (which is transmitted as cookie or url parameter) the session count remains the same. If the parameter is not transmitted a new session is created.

Usually all browsers keep the session id cookie over multiple requests and even multiple tabs or windows (except for incognito tabs/windows of course).

There are multiple reasons why your session count is larger than you user count.

- Sessions are held in tomcat for a period of time, with 2 hours being the default. You can change this amount in tomcat settings. So if 100 user logins into your application in first hour, and 100 in second, your total session count will be 200, even if the first 100 users are idle.
- Robots like the google bot tend to create tons of sessions. If your page is publicly available check the access logs if there are some bots visiting your page.
- If your application is behind the loadbalancer or proxy which are continuously 'pinging' your application for its availability, this pings can create sessions as well.
- Finally there are a lot of 'funny' ways your app can get requests from browsers, for example search results prefetching and similar.
- Also keep in mind that session is bound to the domain name of the site. So if a user connects to your site via multiple domains (for example [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) for content and static.domain.com for images) each of the connections will have its own session.

Now, there are different way to prevent unneeded session creation, depending on what your exact problem is (and if it is a problem at all).

- If you have parts of your application that don't require a session ensure that you don't call `request.getSession()` somewhere in your code. Also in the jsp you can explicitly turn off session with `<%@ page session="false" %>`
- The the session timeout lower to make them expire quicker in tomcat/conf/web.xml `<session-config><session-timeout>30</session-timeout></session-config>`
  The session-timeout value is in minutes.

Finally if you are interested in what is really happening in your application, get yourself an APM (application performance management) tool like [MoSKito](http://www.moskito.org)